# Jenkins Environment Variable String Interpolation for Setting Custom Workspace

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I am using a multibranch pipeline in Jenkins and I need to set the name of the custom workspace directory dynamically based on the branch name that is being built. When I define the custom workspace for the pipeline, I attempt to access the environment variable that contains the branch name as follows:

```
pipeline {

  agent {

    node {

      label 'master'

      customWorkspace 'some/path/${BRANCH_NAME}'
```

However, during `git init` of the workspace, the string interpolation does not happen. Instead of inserting whatever the branch name is into the string, it tries to set the workspace name as `'${BRANCH_NAME}'` without interpolating the branch name variable. If I interpolate the variable outside the `agent` block (for example, if I interpolate the variable in a `stage` block), the string interpolation occurs perfectly fine and I can receive the name of the branch from Jenkins.

What might be the cause of this problem? Are there any other ways to set a custom workspace based on the branch name in a multibranch pipeline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The string interpolation works with double quotes, but does not work with single quotes. When I change the syntax to the following, it works:

```
pipeline {

  agent {

    node {

      label 'master'

      customWorkspace "some/path/${BRANCH_NAME}"
```

Notice the double quotes used around the `customWorkspace` definition.

Apparently, Groovy cannot execute string interpolation on single-quoted strings. For some reason, however, string interpolation in single-quoted strings works outside the `agent` block (such as in a `stage` block), but refuses to work in the example above.

Comment: String interpolation does not work on strings with single quotes (not in any case). This is the intended behavior as you can see in the documentation here: https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation